# smb transfers slow between 2008r2 and 10.6.8

Tags: mac, windows-server-2008-r2, smb

GB Network performance is slow with SMB(45MB/s) compared to FTP (105 MB/s).

Any hint how to improve?

Thank you.

Comment: Are the files hosted on Server 2008R2 or Mac OSX? It's almost certainly a SMB query goof up.

Comment: SMB is slower in theory as it passes data wrapped in commands and there are additional data verification. FTP pretty much dumps the file over TCP and is very prone to error. However, your SMB performance seems to be unusually low compared to FTP.

Comment: The files are hosted on 2008R2. I would expect a reading performance of up to 100 MB/s. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

On your Server 2008 R2 machine I would run these commands one at a time from an elevated command prompt (if you haven't already disabled UAC).

```
netsh interface tcp set global autotuning=disabled
netsh interface tcp set global chimney=disabled
netsh interface tcp set global rss=disabled
```

Then reboot your server and test performance again. I know in my own experience this has vastly improved network speeds.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using an NFS share? , while this doesn't help smb at all I find it faster on my Openfiler server. 10.6 and 10.7 also makes it easy to mount an NFS share with disk utility.

On a side note, do you have severe finder lag while browsing the smb share? It was so bad with 10.6 and server 2000 that I could find files faster in terminal!